# how to improve my class to create output files

Tags: c++, io

As I need this quite often, I would like to write a class handling main ofstream activities.

Something that I could use like this:

```
OutputFile out("output.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   out << i << "\n";
```

To this end, I wrote the following class:

```
class OutputFile {
  std::string filename;
  std::ofstream out;

 public:
  explicit OutputFile(std::string filename) {
    this->filename = filename;
    out.open("output/" + filename);
  }
  ~OutputFile() {
    out.close();
  }
  std::ofstream& operator()() { return out; }
};
```

which is almost what I wanted, however I'm overloading the operator `()`, such that in the example above I have to use

```
out() << i << "\n";
```

How should I modify my class such that I can use as

```
out << i << "\n";
```

Comment: You seem to want to us std::ofstream as public base class not data member.

Comment: No need for the destructor. `std::ofstream` will close the file for you automatically when the `out` variables lifetime ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can overload `operator<<` in your class.

```cpp
class OutputFile {
  std::string filename;
  std::ofstream out;

 public:
  explicit OutputFile(const std::string &filename)
    : filename(filename), out("output/" + filename) {}

  template<typename T>
  OutputFile& operator<<(const T &value) {
    out << value;
    return *this;
  }
};
```